# Getting the delegate to work between two view controllers

Tags: iphone, ios, delegates, protocols

I am a newbie to iPhone development and have some basic questions to ask about `protocols` and `delegates`. I have two view controllers: view controller and viewcontroller2nd. I have *UITextField* in one of them and would like to type something (like a name) in it and in the viewcontroller2nd, I have a *UILabel* and i would like it to appear Hello, name when the UITextField is changed.

I am following this video: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=odk-rr_mzUo to get the basic delegate to work in a single view controller.

I am using protocols to implement this:

**SampleDelegate.h**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@protocol ProcessDelegate <UITextFieldDelegate>
@optional
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField;
@end

@interface SampleDelegate : NSObject
{
    id <ProcessDelegate> delegate;
}

@property (retain) id delegate;

@end
```

**SampleDelegate.m**

```
#import "SampleDelegate.h"

@implementation SampleDelegate

@synthesize delegate;

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField{

    lbl.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Hello, %@",txtField.text];
    [txtField resignFirstResponder];

}

@end
```

**ViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "SampleDelegate.h"

@interface ViewController : UIViewController <ProcessDelegate>
{
    IBOutlet UITextField *txtField;
}

@end
```

**Viewcontroller.m**

```
#import "ViewController.h"


@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

**ViewController2nd.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController2nd : UIViewController <ProcessDelegate> {

    IBOutlet UILabel *lbl;
}



@end
```

and **ViewController2nd.m** is standard code from Xcode.

My question is how do i link my delegate function to my viewcontroller and viewcontroller2nd to get it working?

Pardon me if the question is stupid.. Need some guidance. Do point me any other mistakes that i am doing as well.. Thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your delegation is a bit... Off.

Firstly:  Don't override UIKit delegate methods through protocol inheritance.  It's pointless.  Why not just make your class conform to the specified delegate in the first place?

```
@protocol ProcessDelegate //No more protocol inheritance!
 //...
@end
```

Secondly:  When an object has defined a protocol, a valid instance of that object must be in use by its delegate (or at least passed to it).  So, anything that wants to be the delegate of `SampleDelegate` (really a bad name for a ***class***, by the way) would initialize a valid `SampleDelegate` object, and call `-setDelegate:` as though it were any other property.

```
//#import "SampleDelegate"
@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    //make this a property, so it isn't crushed when the function exits.
    SampleDelegate *myDelegateObject = [[SampleDelegate alloc]init];
    [myDelegateObject setDelegate:self];  //conform to the delegate
}
```

Thirdly: You don't actually define any delegate methods!  What's the point of delegation if there's nothing to delegate!l

```
@protocol ProcessDelegate 
 -(void)someMethod;
@end
```

Fourth, and most important: ***Never, ever, ever, ever use the `retain`, or `strong` storage specifiers with a delegate!***  Delegate objects are supposed to be `weak` or `assign` to prevent nasty retain cycles.

```
@property (assign, nomatomic) id delegate;
```

Comment: what is the simplest way to solve the problem i said at the top?

Comment: Use articles and documentation on the delegate pattern, not some random iOS YouTube video (of which there seem to be a million inaccurate ones) to learn.  And above all, experiment!  You don't get slapped for throwing an exception every once in a while!